# Concurrents Web Request Async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webrequest

I have a little problem that I can't resolve. Maybe some of you will be able to help me. This code seems to me logic and should work but I don't understand what's wrong.

**Current code C# :**

```
static void Main(string[] args){
 string data = "Login=Max";
 byte[] dataStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes();

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var req = WebRequest.Create("http://172.25.110.64:8082/auth/login/");
  req.Method = "POST";
  req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  req.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
  req.BeginGetResponse(EndGetResponseCallback, req);
}

}

static void EndGetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result){

 var req = (WebRequest)result.AsyncState;
 req.EndGetResponse(result);
 Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());

 }
```

I can't put data in the request without triggering an exception and if I remove data there is a problem with the result and trigger also an exception.

How can I fix this? I'm sure the solution isn't so hard to do :)

Comment: In general, you should use a UTF-8 stream, rather than an ASCII one. All valid ASCII sequences will appear the same either way, but UTF-8 gives you the full Unicode range of characters.

Comment: What exceptions are you getting, and where are they thrown?

Comment: Here's my exception throwned during BeginGetResponse :

System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: 'You must provide a request body if you set ContentLength>0 or SendChunked==true.  Do this by calling [Begin]GetRequestStream before [Begin]GetResponse.'

Comment: The exception seems self-explanatory to me @MadeckFromEarth. You've set the content length to the length of the datastream, but haven't included the datastream in the request body. What is the exception you get when you put the data in the request body?

Comment: I'm a beginner how to include data in the request ?? What's to best way  ?

Comment: @MadeckFromEarth: Take a look at Steps 6-8 here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class